# Avoid JDBC spring session | principal name null

Tags: spring, session, jdbc, spring-security, spring-jdbc

found principal name = null. In spring_session table.

I am using spring JDBC session for storing session in database.

Is there any why to avoid null entries in spring_session?

Comment: Did you find a solution @Sunil

Comment: No solutions founded yet.